# Performing Jaccard similarity between two columns

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer

I want to create a column which is the score of similarity between two string columns using Jaccard similarity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index

Does using to_utf8 effect the score created? is there another way to do this.

My attempt:

```
let T = datatable(column1:string, column2:string)
[
   "David", "D@vid",
   "Jan3", "Jane",
   "Danny", "Danni",
];
T
| extend array1 = to_utf8(column1)
| extend array2 = to_utf8(column2)
| extend unionArray = array_concat(array1, array2)
| extend intersectArray = set_intersect(array1, array2)
| extend differenceArray = set_difference(unionArray, intersectArray)
| extend jaccardSimilarity = todouble(array_length(differenceArray)) / todouble(array_length(unionArray))
| where jaccardSimilarity != 1
| distinct column1, column2, jaccardSimilarity
| sort by jaccardSimilarity desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code to achieve your requirement.

```
let T = datatable(column1:string, column2:string)
[
   "David", "D@vid",
   "Jan3", "Jane",
   "Danny", "Danni",
   "Rakesh", "Rakes"
];
T
| extend array1 = to_utf8(column1)
| extend array2 = to_utf8(column2)
| extend inter=set_intersect(array1,array2)
| extend un=set_union(array1,array2)
| extend jaccardSimilarity = iff(isempty(un), todouble(0), todouble(array_length(inter)) / todouble(array_length(un)))
| where jaccardSimilarity != 1
| distinct column1, column2, jaccardSimilarity
| sort by jaccardSimilarity desc;
```

**Output:**

[image]